# Redirected url not picked from urls.py

Tags: python, django

I am very new to Python and Django.
I am using Django - 1.4.5. I am trying to get user input from form, redirect the url with the user input like

```
Httpresponseredirect('abc/xyz/%s' %variable)
```

I could see in browser that the response is redirected, but it throws a 404 error. The *urls.py* also has the `url` defined.

*urls.py*

```
urlpatterns = pattern('',
   url (r'abc/xyz/(?P<variable>)/pqr' , 'view_name')
)
```

Can you please throw some light on it.

---

On further debugging I could figure out that the issue is with passing the argument to `reverse` function. When I pass a static page with no arguments, it redirects to the correct view. But when I redirect with arguments it throws me a `NoreverseMatch` error. I am redirecting it this way

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('view_name', kwargs= {'group':'group'}))
```

In *urls.py* it is defined as:

```
url (r'app/$' , 'app.view.app') ,         
url (r'^my/first/(?P<group>)/$ , 'app.webapi.json.list_record', name ='view_name;),
```

`list_record` is a function in *app.webapi.json.py*.

Please let me know if any more details is required.

Comment: Could you show an example url where do you see the response is redirected? (there is for sure a problem with regexp)

Comment: And show where you use the `Httpresponseredirect('abc/xyz/%s' %variable)`

Comment: You should post your actual code... `(?P<variable>)` doesn't actually match anything since it has no patterns in it and `Httpresponseredirect('abc/xyz/%s' %variable)` doesn't contain the correct url. At this point, people can only correct your mistakes writing pseudo code which probably won't help solve your specific problem...

Comment: If the problem is not what suhail recommended, show use your rool urlconf

Answer (score 1):

User [reverse function](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/http/urls/#reverse) in you view, first add a url name:

```
Httpresponseredirect(reverse('my_view_name', args=[variable]))
```

and (like @sushail said) fix the regexp:

```
urlpatterns = pattern('',
   url (r'^abc/xyz/(?P<variable>)/pqr/$' , 'view_name', name='my_view_name')
)
```

Comment: When i use reverse i get "NoReverseMatch".

Comment: is 'view_name' a function?

Answer (score 0):

you need to use complete path as the regexpression matchs  abc/xyz/..../pqr

```
Httpresponseredirect('/abc/xyz/%s/pqr/' %variable)
```

and like  (like @lalo said)

```
urlpatterns = pattern('',
   url (r'^abc/xyz/(?P<variable>)/pqr/$' , 'view_name')
)
```

please checkwith `/` at begining and end, what is the `view_name`, it looks like you must have such a view in project directory,or you have to add the apppath in urlpatterns

```
`urlpatterns = pattern('<yourappname>.views',`
```

Comment: Yes, maybe your regexp should be `r'^abc/xyz/(?P<variable>)/pqr/$'`